# WPF Text Block Wont Show Property Change at Run-Time

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, mvvm, .net-4.5

I have a text block as follows

```
<TextBlock x:Name="lblErrorMessage" 
           Grid.Row="2" 
           Foreground="Red"   
           Margin="{Binding ControlMargin}" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
           Background="Aqua"
           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
           Text="{Binding Error}"/>
```

And a property in a view behind

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The error message
    /// </summary>
    private string _error = "kkbkbkbkbjK";

    /// <summary>
    /// The error message
    /// </summary>
    public string Error
    {
        //return the error message
        get { return _error; }
        set
        {
            //set the error message
            _error = value;

            //fire the property changed event
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Error"));
        }
    }
```

I then have a method which is executed via an ICommand that updates Error

```
 //set the error message
 Error = "Login Succeeded";
```

My problem is that other bindings work (such as the Margin shown below) but the text block "lblErrorMessage" absolutely refuses to show the message.

If I set the Error property in the constructor it shows.
If I set the _error variable that shows

It seems that if I set the property at runtime it wont pick up the change.

I have tried every combination of the "Two-Way" "PropertyChanged" etc settings but no banana yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try renaming the prop from Error to something else?

Comment: @StevenWood, assuming that _kkbkbkbkbjK_ displays initially, this code should work. I can see you raise `PropertyChanged` event but does your class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?

Comment: OMG! I had declared the proprtychanging event but I hadnt inherited the IPropertyChanged interface. Put this as an answer and ill be happy to accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sum up comments.

Code which you published is fine as you raise `PropertyChanged` event with correct property name when `Error` has changed but if your class does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface this will not work.

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
```